# Como fazer update de vários registros com valores diferentes em lote com Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Imaginem que eu tenho a seguinte tabela Clientes no MongoDb com as informações abaixo:

```
[{
  "idCliente": 1233
  "idPlataforma": 112,
  "nmQtdeVisitas": 1,
  "dtPrVisita": "2021-11-10 13:00:00",
}]
[{
  "idCliente": 2344
  "idPlataforma": 321,
  "nmQtdeVisitas": 1,
  "dtPrVisita": "2021-11-10 13:31:27",
}]
```

Por sua vez, eu acabo recebendo uma atualização desses dados em lote json:

```
[{"idCliente":1233,"idPlataforma":112,"nmVisitas":3,"dtVisita":"2021-11-11 15:32:21"},
{"idCliente":2344,"idPlataforma":321,"nmVisitas":2,"dtVisita":"2021-11-10 20:11:07"}]
```

E preciso atualizar os registros no meu banco utilizando como condição no filtro os campos **idCliente** e **idPlataforma** e passando os novos valores de acordo com os filtros acima.

Ficando assim no MongoDB:

```
[{
  "idCliente": 1233
  "idPlataforma": 112,
  "nmQtdeVisitas": 3,
  "dtPrVisita": "2021-11-11 15:32:21",
}]
[{
  "idCliente": 2344
  "idPlataforma": 321,
  "nmQtdeVisitas": 2,
  "dtPrVisita": "2021-11-10 20:11:07",
}]
```

Em linhas gerais, se fosse ser feito uma query no SQL, ficaria assim:

```
UPDATE Clientes SET nmVisitas = 3, dtVisita = '2021-11-11 15:21:21' WHERE idCliente=1233 and idPltaforma=112
UPDATE Clientes SET nmVisitas = 2, dtVisita = '2021-11-10 20:11:07' WHERE idCliente=2344 and idPltaforma=321
```

Todavia gostaria de saber se é possível fazer `UPDATE` em lotes, utilizando `update_many()` do **Pymongo** atualizando os campos com os novos valores de acordo com os filtros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que utilizar um [Bulk Write](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bulk.html) seja a melhor opção para o seu caso. Ele permite que você escreva diversas operações e execute elas em uma única chamada.

O problema de usar um update_many, é que o valor do filtro deve ser igual e esse não é seu caso.

```
from pymongo import UpdateOne
db.test.bulk_write([
    UpdateOne(
      { 'idCliente': 1233, 'idPlataforma': 112 },
      { '$set': { 'nmVisitas ': 3, 'dtVisita' = '2021-11-11 15:21:21' } }
    ),
    UpdateOne(
      { 'idCliente': 2344, 'idPlataforma': 321 },
      { '$set': { 'nmVisitas ': 2, 'dtVisita' = '2021-11-10 20:11:07' } }
    ),
])
```